# Handling polymorphisms with large amount of very similar classes in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am making a simulation with different particles. They all have simular
behaviours, are all stored in the same list with other particles of potentially
different sub-types, and are treated equally by the rest of the system. I therefore created the class Particle, and attempted different methods of polymorphism. This is a simplified version of what I roughly want to achieve, written in pseudo-code:

```
//Movement methods
Randomwalk() {//code}
Diffusion() {//code}
Steered_Motion() {//code}

//Special actions
Pollute() {//code}
Cleanup() {//code}

//Particles
Particle_Type       Movement_Method           Special_Action
Oil                 Diffusion()               Pollute()
Sorbent             Diffusion()               Cleanup()
Packman_random      Randomwalk()              Cleanup()
Packman_steered     Steered_Motion()          Cleanup()
... (50 more rows)
```

I have thought of three methods to achieve this, but two of them only work effectively for a small amount of particle types (<= 10), while the third method was a hopefull dream shattered by the way the DataTable class works in C#.

The first method I tried was defining an Enum with the different particle types, adding a Field to the Particle class which defined what kind of particle it was, and used a switch statement using that field to determine which movement method and which special action to call.

```
public class Particle {
     public enum ParticleType: int {
          Oil = 0,
          Sorbent = 1,
          //...etc
     }
     
     public readonly ParticleType TypeOfParticle;

     Movement() {
          switch(TypeOfParticle) {
               case ParticleType.Oil:
                    Diffusion();
                    break;
               case ParticleType.Sorbent:
                    Diffusion();
                    break;
          }
     }
}
```

However, as some types required additional fields, this left a mess of various fields that where used by only one of the sub types. In addition, the Enum type does not have any build in support for requiring uniqueness, which means two particle types could end up triggering the same case in the switch statements if the Enum definition would not be properly checked for the value assignment.

The second method was using inheritance. Here I still used the same Particle class, but had every particle type be a child of the Particle class.

```
public class Particle {
     virtual public void Movement() {}

     //Define methods
     Randomwalk() {//some code}
     Diffusion() {//some code}
     Steered_Motion() {//some code}
}

public class Oil: Particle {
     override public void Movement() {
          Diffusion();
     }
}

public class Sorbent: Particle {
     override public void Movement() {
          Diffusion();
     }
}
```

While this solves the problem of having fields only for some of the types, it creates a very long list with a ton of classes. Maybe it is just me, but managing this list of types really feels like a chore. Therefore I started looking for something among the lines of the third method.

The thrird, desired method would be something among the lines of using a DataTable to create a table, with all the different particle types as rows, and the movement methods and special actions as columns. Running the methods would be done using delegates. Unfortunately, DataTables are populated at Run Time, while I need to define the classess at compile time. In addition managing DataTables also does not sound like the most comfortable task.

So I finally have come to ask you what you would do. Is there any type similar to DataTable that I could use? I'm a physics & mathematics student, with not that many hours of programming, so even if something sounds very basic, I might have totally missed it. Really appreciate any input!
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I don't have an overall answer but want to point out that in your example above you would(could) have a DiffusionParticle class, which has that `Movement()` method, and which both `Oil` and `Sorbent` inherit from. -- Since you're so concerned about maintenance, do you have hundreds of different types and/or are they very dynamic? (I mean what the population is)

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I would like to have a large (50+) and dynamic list of particle types, such that I can quickly add a new particle, change a particles' movement method and so on. I don't quite get your suggestion for having Oil and Sorbent particles inherit from DiffusionParticle, since C# only allows for inheritance from one base class, while I want the particles to inherit more than just the movement, such as the special actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with my own solution to this problem, and want to share it for anyone who may end up with a similar question to mine.

I have created a custom class that serves as a datatable like entry determining the desired methods and behaviours of each child class of `Particle`, and have each particle search for its own behaviour in the table.

```
internal class ParticleTable {
     //Fields for devining suptype behaviour
     internal readonly Type SubType;
     internal readonly MotionDelegate MotionMethod;
     internal readonly ActionDelegate ActionMethod;
}

public abstract class Particle {
     //Delegate definitions
     internal delegate void MotionDelegate(Particle self);
     internal delegate void ActionDelegate(Particle self);

     //SubType behaviour definitions
     internal static readonly ImmutableArray<ParticleTable> SubTypes = ImmutableArray.Create(
          new ParticleTable[]{
               new ParticleTable(Particle_Oil, Randomwalk, Pollute);
               new ParticleTable(Particle_Sorbent, Randomwalk, Cleanup);
               //...
          }
     );

     //Update method
     public void ParticleUpdate() {
          //find entry of own type in table
          ParticleTable self_def;
          foreach (ParticleTable sub in SubTypes) {
               if (sub.SubType == this.GetType()) {
                    self_def = sub;
                    break;
               }
          }
          
          //get methods
          MotionDelegate motion = self_def.MotionMethod;
          ActionDelegate action = self_def.ActionMethod;
          
          //execute actions
          motion.Invoke(this);
          action.Invoke(this);
     }
}

//library of subtypes
public class Particle_Oil : Particle {
     //some type specific code
}

public class Particle_Sorbent : Particl {
     //some type specific code
}
//...
```

This way, any configuring can be done in the "table" `Subtype`s by changing the parameter values in the `new ParticleTable()` calls. Any sub type specific code can be written in the dedicated class as normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use delegate to represent your movements and special actions. Or Action, Func which are just delegate too. Depends of your need.
In this example I've included the `Particle` in the delegate so that depending the type of the particle the behavior of the Diffusion delegate may be different by example.
Then you just have a `ParticleFactory` to instantiate your particles properly depending the `ParticleType` you desire.

```
        public delegate void SpecialAction(Particle particle);
        public delegate void Movement(Particle particle);

        public static Movement Diffusion = (particle) => { };
        public static Movement RandomWalk = (particle) => { };
        public static Movement Steered_Motion = (particle) => { };

        public static SpecialAction Pollute = (particle) => { };
        public static SpecialAction Cleanup = (particle) => { };

        public enum ParticleType
        {
            Oil = 0,
            Sorbent = 1,
            Packman_random=2,
            Packman_steered=3,
        }

        public class ParticleFactory
        {
            public static Particle BuildParticle(ParticleType particleType) {
                switch(particleType)
                {
                    case ParticleType.Oil:
                        {
                            return new Particle(particleType, Diffusion, Pollute);
                        }
                    case ParticleType.Sorbent:
                        {
                            return new Particle(particleType, Diffusion, Cleanup);
                        }
                    case ParticleType.Packman_random:
                        {
                            return new Particle(particleType, RandomWalk, Cleanup);
                        }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class Particle {

            private readonly ParticleType particleType;
            private readonly Movement movement;
            private readonly SpecialAction specialAction;


            internal Particle(ParticleType particleType, Movement movement, SpecialAction specialAction)
            {
                this.particleType = particleType;
                this.movement = movement;
                this.specialAction = specialAction;
            }

            public void Move()
            {
                movement.Invoke(this);
            }

            public void Special()
            {
                specialAction.Invoke(this);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
**INHERITANCE**
You can always subclass Particle to provide additional fields on some. Each subclass will have its own fields.

```
public class SubParticle : Particle {
    public int OilParticlesRemoved {get; set;}
}
```

Then the factory does just return a SubParticle instead of Particle.
It remains how to access these fields in the code ... Pattern Matching may help.

```
SubParticle some = new SubParticle();  
switch (some)  
{  
  case Particle particle: // Type pattern
    particle.Move();
    break;  
  case SubParticle subParticle:  // Type pattern
    subparticle.OilParticlesRemoved = 10;
    subparticle.Move();
    break;  
}
```

**Decorator**
Another solution may be to use decorators. In such case methods on `Particle` should be virtual. The Factory return a `Sorbent` decorator which is a `Particle`. But the decorator store more properties than the basic `Particle`.

```
public Particle {
  ...
  public virtual void Move() {
    movement();
  }
  ...
}

public Sorbent : Particle {
  private readonly Particle particle;
  public Sorbent(Particle particle) {
    this.particle = particle;
  }
  public int OilParticlesRemoved {get; set;}

  public override void Move() {
    OilParticlesRemoved = 10;
    particle.Move();
  }
}
```

It remains that if you want to access these properties from code, you have to distinguish the type.

Comment: I like the idea of the particle factory! However, as I described in my question, using one class for the particle types, and specifying the type using enums leaves the problem of handling particle type specific fields. For instance, the Sorbent and Packman particles have a int field storing the number of oil particles they have removed, while other particles do not have this field. I want to avoid having to add the fields of every particle type to every other particle type.

Comment: I've added Inheritance and decorator, take a look if that may help.
I like the factory because when you look the switch it can be read nearly as a datatable. You quickly view column1 is the type, column2 the move and column3 the action.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second approach is the right one, especially if:

- You have a relatively fixed number of particle types that you're modeling,
- Some of the particle types you're modeling have special behavior not shared by other particle types, and/or
- There is any sort of grouping or commonality between particle types that you want to capture as a part of a class hierarchy

```
public abstract class Particle
{
    // standard movement behaviors available to any subclass of Particle
    protected void RandomWalk() {...}
    protected void SteeredMotion() {...}
    protected void Diffusion() {...}

    // standard "special actions" available to subclasses of Particle
    protected void Pollute() {...}
    protected void CleanUp() {...}

    // abstract methods expected to call the above methods
    protected abstract void Move();
    protected abstract void SpecialAction();
}

public class OilParticle : Particle
{
    protected override void Move() { Diffusion(); }
    protected override void SpecialAction() { Pollute(); }
}

public class PackmanRandomParticle : Particle
{
    protected override void Move() { RandomWalk(); }
    protected override void SpecialAction() { CleanUp(); }
}
```

Comment: I do totally agree with what you have written, but the first assumption, the one about having a fixed number of particles, is not met in my case. I am constantly adding extensions to the simulation, and those often include new particle types. I want to have a list of particles that can be quickly changed at any moment, for whatever reason.